# How to get started with Dynamic Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a problem getting started with dynamic jasper. I have a controller class that has a table and would like to convert the table to a fast report using dynamic Jasper so that I can print it out given the current content. Would anybody know how to use Dynamic Jasper? I read the documentation but can't quite understand it. I included my jasper code in the `printAction` function so that it can print out content from the table once pressed. However, I don't understand where do I get `"branch"` and `String.class.getName()` given my classes? Do I have to create a jrxml file first with jasper? How do I basically implement the code so that it will work? The code from `printAction` is the sample code found on their website (http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/). Hope somebody knows how to use this. Thank you.

My controller class:

```
public class ProfileController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField name, age;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Profile> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Profile, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Profile, String> ageColumn;

    ProfileDAO profileDAO = new ProfileDAO();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    //prepare cells
                nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().profileNameProperty());
                ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().profileAgeProperty());

      try() {
        table.setItems(profileDAO.search())
      }catch(){

      }
    }

    @FXML
    private void printAAction() {
        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        DynamicReport dr = drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(),30)
        .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(),30)
        .addColumn("Product Line", "productLine", String.class.getName(),50)
        .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(),50)
        .addColumn("Item Code", "id", Long.class.getName(),30,true)
        .addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(),60,true)
        .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(),70,true)
        .addGroups(2)
        .setTitle("November 2006 sales report")
        .setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
        .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)
        .setUseFullPageWidth(true)
        .build();

        JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(TestRepositoryProducts.getDummyCollection());
        JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);    //finally display the report report     
    }

}
```

Profile Model

```
public class Profile {
    private final SimpleStringProperty profileName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty profileAge;

    public Profile() {
        this("", "");
    }

    public Profile(String profileName, String profileAge) {
        this.profileName = new SimpleStringProperty(profileName);
        this.profileAge = new SimpleStringProperty(profileAge);; 
    }

    //getter
    public String getProfileName() {
        return profileName.get()
    }

    public String getProfileAge() {
        return profileAge.get()
    }   
    //setter
    public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
        this.profileName.set(profileName);
    }

    public void setProfileAge(String profileAge){
        this.profileAge.set(profileAge);
    }

    //property
    public StringProperty profileNameProperty(){
        return profileName;
    }

    public StringProperty profileAgeProperty() {
        return profileAge;
    }
}
```

ProfileDAO

```
ublic class ProfileDAO {
    public ObservableList<Profile> search() throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
        //declare PreparedStatement & ResultSet
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;        
        //Declare a SELECT statement
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM profiles";

        //Execute SELECT statement
        try {
            //initializing PreparedStatement
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
            //initializing ResultSet via SqliteConnection method
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            ObservableList<Profile> profileList = getProfileList(resultSet);

            //Return Profile object
            return titlesList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e);
            //Return exception
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if(preparedStatement != null)
            {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if(resultSet != null)
            {
                resultSet.close();
            }  
        }       
    }   

    private static ObservableList<Profile> getProfileList(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //Declare a observable List
        ObservableList<Profile> profileList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Profile profile = new Profile();
            profile.setProfileName(resultSet.getInt("name"));
            profile.setProfileAge(resultSet.getString("age"));

            //Add to  ObservableList
            profileList.add(profile);
        }
        //return empList (ObservableList of Employees)
        return titlesList;
    }   
}
```

Comment: its not a duplicate.

Comment: Anybody who is wondering how to get started with DynamicJasper, please look at the answer from this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680997/why-jasperviewer-swing-based-component-is-not-dispaying-report-at-javafx-proje/51685183#51685183). I finally solved it. Good luck everybody.

Comment: @Alex K: Please remove it as duplicate since it is not a duplicate. It is asking about implementation and an example which was not provided in the link you provided. Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: You asked about noclassdeffounderror before your last question's modification. Ok, but your question (there are a lot of questions at your post) is too broad. IMHO, it is not really a question

Comment: Looks like it is better to remove this post because you created another post and solved a problem described at this post too