# Why JasperViewer (Swing based component) is not dispaying report at JavaFX project?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jasper-reports

I have 2 projects which run JasperReports. One which runs on JavaFX and one with just plain Java and a main class. Now, if I ran the plain Java project jasperReport works and displays (vai *JasperViewer* class), but with the JavaFX project it works but no report displays after clicking the button.

Why does it work for plain Java class but not for JavaFX?
 
What can I do to make it work in JavaFX?

Everything else is the same aside from them being javaFx and plain Java. I downloaded the following jar files for this:

- Dynamic Jasper 5.0.5. jar
- jasperreports 5.6.0.jar
- commons-logging 1.2.jar
- commons beanutils 1.9.2.jar
- commons digester 2.1.jar

  commons collections 3.2.2.jar

Here are the projects:

**NO.1. JavaFX:**

DynaReportApp.java class

```
package jasperreport;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
public class DynaReportApp {
    public DynaReportApp() {

    }
    public EmployeeReport start() {
        Collection<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Employee(101, "Ravinder Shah",  67000, (float) 2.5));
        list.add(new Employee(102, "John Smith",  921436, (float) 9.5));
        list.add(new Employee(103, "Kenneth Johnson",  73545, (float) 1.5));
        list.add(new Employee(104, "John Travolta",  43988, (float) 0.5));
        list.add(new Employee(105, "Peter Parker",  93877, (float) 3.5));
        list.add(new Employee(106, "Leonhard Euler",  72000, (float) 2.3));
        list.add(new Employee(107, "William Shakespeare",  33000, (float) 1.4));
        list.add(new Employee(108, "Arup Bindal",  92000, (float) 6.2));
        list.add(new Employee(109, "Arin Kohfman",  55000, (float) 8.5));
        list.add(new Employee(110, "Albert Einstein",  89000, (float) 8.2));

        EmployeeReport report = new EmployeeReport(list);
        return report;

    }
}
```

Employee.java class

```
package jasperreport;

public class Employee {
    private int empNo;
    private String name;    
    private int salary;
    private float commission;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int empNo, String name, int salary, float commission) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.name = name;        
        this.salary = salary;
        this.commission = salary*commission;
    }

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public float getCommission() {
        return commission;
    }

    public void setCommission(float commission) {
        this.commission = commission;
    }
}
```

EmployeeReport.java class

```
package jasperreport;

import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.ClassicLayoutManager;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.Style;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilderException;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.DynamicReportBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.StyleBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Border;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Font;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.HorizontalAlign;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Transparency;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.VerticalAlign;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.entities.columns.AbstractColumn;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class EmployeeReport {
    private final Collection<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public EmployeeReport(Collection<Employee> c) {
        list.addAll(c);
    }

    public JasperPrint getReport() throws ColumnBuilderException, JRException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Style headerStyle = createHeaderStyle();
        Style detailTextStyle = createDetailTextStyle();        
        Style detailNumberStyle = createDetailNumberStyle();        
        DynamicReport dynaReport = getReport(headerStyle, detailTextStyle,detailNumberStyle);
        JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dynaReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
        return jp;
    }

    private Style createHeaderStyle() {        
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM_BOLD);
        sb.setBorder(Border.THIN());
        sb.setBorderBottom(Border.PEN_2_POINT());
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setTransparency(Transparency.OPAQUE);        
        return sb.build();
    }

    private Style createDetailTextStyle(){
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM);
        sb.setBorder(Border.DOTTED());        
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);        
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.LEFT);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setPaddingLeft(5);        
        return sb.build();
    }

      private Style createDetailNumberStyle(){
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM);
        sb.setBorder(Border.DOTTED());        
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);        
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setPaddingRight(5);        
        return sb.build();
    }



    private AbstractColumn createColumn(String property, Class type,
            String title, int width, Style headerStyle, Style detailStyle)
            throws ColumnBuilderException {
        AbstractColumn columnState = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                .setColumnProperty(property, type.getName()).setTitle(
                        title).setWidth(Integer.valueOf(width))
                .setStyle(detailStyle).setHeaderStyle(headerStyle).build();
        return columnState;
    }

    private DynamicReport getReport(Style headerStyle, Style detailTextStyle, Style detailNumStyle) throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        DynamicReportBuilder report=new DynamicReportBuilder();

        AbstractColumn columnEmpNo = createColumn("empNo", Integer.class,"Employee Number", 30, headerStyle, detailTextStyle);
        AbstractColumn columnName = createColumn("name", String.class,"Name", 30, headerStyle, detailTextStyle);        
        AbstractColumn columnSalary = createColumn("salary", Integer.class,"Salary", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
        AbstractColumn columnCommission = createColumn("commission", Float.class,"Commission", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
        report.addColumn(columnEmpNo)
                .addColumn(columnName).addColumn(columnSalary).addColumn(columnCommission);

        StyleBuilder titleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
        titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        titleStyle.setFont(new Font(20, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));

        StyleBuilder subTitleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
        subTitleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        subTitleStyle.setFont(new Font(Font.MEDIUM, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));



        report.setTitle("Employee Report");
        report.setTitleStyle(titleStyle.build());
        report.setSubtitle("Commission received by Employee");
        report.setSubtitleStyle(subTitleStyle.build());
        report.setUseFullPageWidth(true); 
        return report.build();
    }     
}
```

JasperReport.java

```
package jasperreport;

import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilderException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class JasperReport extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();   
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                DynaReportApp dynaReportApp = new DynaReportApp();
                JasperPrint jp = dynaReportApp.start().getReport();
                JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jp);
                jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
                JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);

            } catch (JRException | ColumnBuilderException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println( ex);
            }
        });



        root.getChildren().addAll(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JasperReport");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();         
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

**NO.2. Ordinary Java**

Employee.java

```
package jasperreporttest;

public class Employee {
    private int empNo;
    private String name;    
    private int salary;
    private float commission;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int empNo, String name, int salary, float commission) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.name = name;        
        this.salary = salary;
        this.commission = salary*commission;
    }

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public float getCommission() {
        return commission;
    }

    public void setCommission(float commission) {
        this.commission = commission;
    }
}
```

EmployeeReport.java

```
package jasperreporttest;

import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.ClassicLayoutManager;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicReport;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.Style;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilderException;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.DynamicReportBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.StyleBuilder;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Border;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Font;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.HorizontalAlign;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.Transparency;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.constants.VerticalAlign;
import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.entities.columns.AbstractColumn;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class EmployeeReport {
    private final Collection<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public EmployeeReport(Collection<Employee> c) {
        list.addAll(c);
    }

    public JasperPrint getReport() throws ColumnBuilderException, JRException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Style headerStyle = createHeaderStyle();
        Style detailTextStyle = createDetailTextStyle();        
        Style detailNumberStyle = createDetailNumberStyle();        
        DynamicReport dynaReport = getReport(headerStyle, detailTextStyle,detailNumberStyle);
        JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dynaReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
        return jp;
    }

    private Style createHeaderStyle() {        
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM_BOLD);
        sb.setBorder(Border.THIN());
        sb.setBorderBottom(Border.PEN_2_POINT());
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setTransparency(Transparency.OPAQUE);        
        return sb.build();
    }

    private Style createDetailTextStyle(){
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM);
        sb.setBorder(Border.DOTTED());        
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);        
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.LEFT);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setPaddingLeft(5);        
        return sb.build();
    }

      private Style createDetailNumberStyle(){
        StyleBuilder sb=new StyleBuilder(true);
        sb.setFont(Font.VERDANA_MEDIUM);
        sb.setBorder(Border.DOTTED());        
        sb.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);        
        sb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sb.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
        sb.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
        sb.setPaddingRight(5);        
        return sb.build();
    }



    private AbstractColumn createColumn(String property, Class type,
            String title, int width, Style headerStyle, Style detailStyle)
            throws ColumnBuilderException {
        AbstractColumn columnState = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                .setColumnProperty(property, type.getName()).setTitle(
                        title).setWidth(Integer.valueOf(width))
                .setStyle(detailStyle).setHeaderStyle(headerStyle).build();
        return columnState;
    }

    private DynamicReport getReport(Style headerStyle, Style detailTextStyle, Style detailNumStyle) throws ColumnBuilderException, ClassNotFoundException {

        DynamicReportBuilder report=new DynamicReportBuilder();

        AbstractColumn columnEmpNo = createColumn("empNo", Integer.class,"Employee Number", 30, headerStyle, detailTextStyle);
        AbstractColumn columnName = createColumn("name", String.class,"Name", 30, headerStyle, detailTextStyle);        
        AbstractColumn columnSalary = createColumn("salary", Integer.class,"Salary", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
        AbstractColumn columnCommission = createColumn("commission", Float.class,"Commission", 30, headerStyle, detailNumStyle);
        report.addColumn(columnEmpNo)
                .addColumn(columnName).addColumn(columnSalary).addColumn(columnCommission);

        StyleBuilder titleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
        titleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        titleStyle.setFont(new Font(20, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));

        StyleBuilder subTitleStyle=new StyleBuilder(true);
        subTitleStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
        subTitleStyle.setFont(new Font(Font.MEDIUM, Font._FONT_GEORGIA, true));



        report.setTitle("Employee Report");
        report.setTitleStyle(titleStyle.build());
        report.setSubtitle("Commission received by Employee");
        report.setSubtitleStyle(subTitleStyle.build());
        report.setUseFullPageWidth(true); 
        return report.build();
    }     
}
```

JasperReportTest

```
package jasperreporttest;

import ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.builders.ColumnBuilderException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class JasperReportTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Employee(101, "Ravinder Shah",  67000, (float) 2.5));
        list.add(new Employee(102, "John Smith",  921436, (float) 9.5));
        list.add(new Employee(103, "Kenneth Johnson",  73545, (float) 1.5));
        list.add(new Employee(104, "John Travolta",  43988, (float) 0.5));
        list.add(new Employee(105, "Peter Parker",  93877, (float) 3.5));
        list.add(new Employee(106, "Leonhard Euler",  72000, (float) 2.3));
        list.add(new Employee(107, "William Shakespeare",  33000, (float) 1.4));
        list.add(new Employee(108, "Arup Bindal",  92000, (float) 6.2));
        list.add(new Employee(109, "Arin Kohfman",  55000, (float) 8.5));
        list.add(new Employee(110, "Albert Einstein",  89000, (float) 8.2));

        EmployeeReport report = new EmployeeReport(list);

        try {
            JasperPrint jp = report.getReport();
            JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jp);
            jasperViewer.setVisible(true);

        } catch (JRException | ColumnBuilderException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I did. There seems to be no error. Everything is generated but for some reason it just won't display in javaFX.

Comment: @Marvin: Yes, I just didn't include it for the second project because it works. It's only JavaFX(the 1st) that doesn't want to finish creating the dynamicJasperDesign.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that jasper is a swing app and that it can't be read via JavaFX node?

Comment: Yes, JasperViewer is a Swing based. Did you read this: [Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, this has been one heck of a roller-coaster but I finally found my solution and I hope it will help others as well. So apparently the above approach is correct. Everything is right to the dot. The only thing missing is `jasper-compliler-jdlt 5.5.23.jar`. So as long as you have all the above jars it should work. I also noticed that for some reason if you use a higher DynamicJasper version like 5.1.1, the whole thing won't work. So just try to keep the following jar files(list of complete jar files can be found below) as well as the above implementation and you should be fine. Cheers and happy coding :)

List of jar files

```
DynamicJasper 5.0.5. jar
commons-beanutils 1.9.2.jar
commons-collections 3.2.2.jar
commons-digester 2.1.jar
commons-logging 1.2.jar
jasperreports 5.6.0.jar or jasperreports 6.0.0.ar
jasper-compliler-jdlt 5.5.23.jar
```